# Javafx TabPane tab switcher

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tabs

I'm developing app using javafx 2.0.
[image]

I want to place several tabs in a single row, maybe draw tab label multiline. How can I remove tab switcher? 
Piece of my fxml with TabPane:

```
<TabPane layoutY="0.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
            <tabs>
              ***
              ***
            </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Can anyone help me?

Upd.
javafx.runtime.version=8.0.60
javafx.runtime.build=b27